# subtracting total budget with total expense

Tags: django, django-orm

models.py

```
class Add(models.Model):
    budget = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True)
    expense = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Views.py

```
def home_page(request):
    bud = Add.objects.aggregate(Sum('budget'))
    exp = Add.objects.aggregate(Sum('expense'))
    context = {'bud':bud, 'exp':exp,'budexp':budexp}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context,)
```

I want to subtract total of bud and total of exp (bud - exp) how could i do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the aggregates in a single query here. This will reduce the amount of "roundtrips" to the database, and thus improve performance as well:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

def home_page(request):
    context = Add.objects.aggregate(
        bud=Sum('budget'),
        exp=Sum('expense'),
        budexp=Sum('budget')-Sum('expense')
    )
    return render(request, 'home.html', context,)
```

Here `context` will have three items: `bud`, `exp`, and `budexp`.

Comment: Let me see if it works bro thanks for sharing this code.

Comment: @MuhammedBilal: note that `bud`, `exp` and `budexp` are here (probably) numbers, not dictionaries that wrap a number, so you should render these in the template as `{{ bud }}`, `{{ exp }}`, and `{{ budexp }}`.

Comment: @MuhammedBilal: what is giving `0`? `{{ budexp }}`? What are `'bud' and `'exp'` here? What items are there in `Add`?

Comment: @MuhammedBilal: you used `F('bud') -F('exp')`? Not something like `F('bud')-F('bud')` right?

Comment: Yes i tried both F('bud') -F('exp')  , and F('bud')   -F('exp') both giving me zero when i see in my console its like this   {'bud': 2000, 'exp': 1000, 'budexp': 0}

Comment: @MuhammedBilal: what if you use the `Sum`s instead (see update).

Comment: is there any other method i just want to show budget left .

Comment: @MuhammedBilal: what would be the problem here? Likely the DBMS will optimize the duplicate sum. Does the above works?

Comment: context = Add.objects.aggregate(
        bud=Sum('budget'),
        exp=Sum('expense'),
        budexp=Sum('budget')-Sum('expense')
    )